# Pass list of complex objects from activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, parcelable

I have a MainActivity with a SearchFragment and a SearchResultFragment.

When the user presses the searchbutton I do a callback from the SearchFragment to the MainActivity with the SearchParameters as parameters.

On the MainActivity I than show a LoadFragment and load the results.
When I receive the results I want to pass the list of result objects to the SearchResultFragment.

What is the best way to do this?

I know you normally do it like this if it was just one result:

```
public static SearchResultFragment newInstance(SearchResult result) {
    SearchResultFragment f = new SearchResultFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("result", result);  // Make result parceable
    f.setArguments(args);
    return f;
}
```

But how do I do this with a list of objects ?

Another solution I can think of is to get a reference to the MainActivity in the onAttach method of the fragment and then call a method getResults() on the MainActivity.

What would be the best way ?

Comment: Use the same callback approach sending the list from the activity to the fragment.

Comment: Is your issue solved or do you need further assistance? Please don't forget to upvote helpful answers and accept the one which helped you most.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In most cases you can avoid the need to pass complex objects but if you cannot, then just use getters and setters. Try something like this:

```
public static SearchResultFragment newInstance(SearchResult result) {
    SearchResultFragment f = new SearchResultFragment();
    f.setResult(result);        
    return f;
}
```

**BUT** try to avoid this, passing the data with a `Bundle` is a much better solution. Use `Parcelable` wherever you can.

Answer (score 4):

*Note: my answer assumes you're trying to pass an aggregation of data to a fragment once. If you're trying to update regularly an existing fragment with new information (new results) then maybe better have a dedicated method in the `Fragment` to both save the results as arguments and update the UI.*

Both approaches may be acceptable, especially depending on the scope you want to give to your search results, but I would favor passing the results as a "static" parameter (meaning not fetched dynamically from the `Activity`) mainly for the following reasons:

- `Fragment`s are intended as reusable pieces of UI, meaning the Android framework allows you to integrate the same `Fragment` in another `Activity` ; in this case it is easier to integrate (more flexible) than if the attached `Activity` has to implement a given getter, and the `Fragment` could actually be constructed by another entity (e.g. a "result fetcher) and attached to the `Activity` without it knowing about the results (eases potential refactoring)
- `Fragment` arguments are retained, meaning that the same `Fragment` initialization code (which fetches the results from the arguments) will also handle `Fragment` automatic reinstantiation after an activity restart (e.g. screen rotation) for example ; otherwise you would additionally have to handle the save and restoration of the results entity yourself

On the other hand, putting the results in a `Bundle` as `Fragment` parameter will be slightly slower since after receiving new results you create an additional structure (the `Bundle`) which you then parcel (serialize) and unparcel (deserialize). It will be faster upon `Activity` restart though since you don't have to parcel it in this case (it has already been done). I just mention it for the sake of completeness though since, unless your results are very big (which is a valid use case but maybe more suited for paged loading then ?), you won't notice and anyway shouldn't care.

To pass several results to a `Fragment` (assuming a single result is an `int`):

```
final Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putIntArray(SearchResultFragment.ARG_NAME_RESULTS, results);  // results being an int[]
fragment.setArguments(args);
```

Just use `Bundle#putIntegerArrayList(String, ArrayList<Integer>)` instead if `results` is of type `ArrayList<Integer>`.